# Trying to sort Pandas DataFrame and get error relating to datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort a Pandas DataFrame by largest to smallest number using the sort_values pandas method and I get the following error

"{TypeError}only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

The column is a 48x1 column of int32 values (after conversion). I am not sure why this is not working since I have already converted the column into integers as the error is asking for. I have tried the flag, ascending=True and get the same error.

```
import pandas as pd

class Report:

    # Define attributes
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_excel = {}
        self.path = "whatever path"
        #self.clean_data = {}

        self.readExcelReport()
        self.cleanData()
        # self.parseData()
        # self.runTest()

    # Grab Excel data
    def readExcelReport(self):
        try:

            # sheet_name=None indicates you want a dictionary of dataframes, each item in the dictionary representing
            # a different worksheet.
            self.raw_excel = pd.read_excel(self.path, sheet_name=0)
            print("data extracted")
            return self.raw_excel
        except:
            print("Could not load excel data")
            return

    def runTest(self):
        print("test")

    def cleanData(self):
        # get rid of unnecessary top rows and rename data frame columns
        clean_data = self.raw_excel[4:]
        tittle = clean_data.iloc[0]

        # bug
        #clean_data.columns = [tittle]

        # correct solution
        clean_data.columns = tittle

        clean_data = clean_data[1:]
        clean_data.insert(3, "Notes", True)
        clean_data.insert(4, "Actions", True)
        clean_data.iloc[0:, 2] = clean_data.iloc[0:, 2].astype(int)

        clean_data.sort_values(by=["Severity"])

        return clean_data

test = Report()
```

Comment: Not quite. That solution is not using a pandas DataFrame. I need to be able to sort the entire DataFrame based on the Severity column.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this for whoever runs into the same error.

The problem is that I was declaring clean_data.columns = [title] as a list by enclosing tittle in []. By doing this and when sorting values, the method clean_data.sort_values takes that row header which is in a list already and puts it into another list causing the error. To solve this just remove the brackets from where I changed the column names. I have updated the script with the right line and commented out the error for reference.